# Subtract values of single row polars frame from multiple row polars frame

Tags: python, python-polars

Lets say I have a polars dataframe like this in python

```py
    newdata = pl.DataFrame({
        'A': [1, 2, 3, 4],
        'B': [5, 6, 7, 8],
        'C': [9, 10, 11, 12],
        'D': [13, 14, 15, 16]
    })
```

And I want to subtract from every value in every column the corresponding value from another frame

```py
baseline = pl.DataFrame({
    'A': [1],
    'B': [2],
    'C': [3],
    'D': [4]
})
```

In pandas, and numpy, the baseline frame is automagically broadcasted to the size of the newdata, and I can just do;

```py
data=newdata-baseline
```

But that doesn't work in polars. So what is the cleanest way to achieve this in polars?

Comment: One way is to do it in a loop: `newdata.with_columns([pl.col(c) - baseline[c] for c in newdata.columns])`

Comment: Thanks @glebcom that works, it was the pl.col on one side but direct indexing on the other side that tripped me up. If you turn your comment into an answer then I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here loop by column names can be used:

```py
newdata.with_columns(
    [pl.col(c) - baseline[c] for c in newdata.columns]
)
```